# Apahce Spark on Redshift vs Apache Spark on HIVE EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hive, amazon-redshift, amazon-emr

I'm doing some studies about Redshift and Hive working at AWS.

I have an application working in Spark, that is in local cluster, working with Apache Hive. Then we will migrate to AWS.

We found that there is a Data Warehouse solution that is Redshift.
Redshift is a Columnar database that is really fast to queries for Tb of data with no big issues. Working with Redshift will not take much time of maintaining. But I have a question, how is the performance of Redshift over Hive?

If I store a Hive with EMR, setting the storage at EMR and handle the metastore with Hive it will take this to process the data with Spark.

What is the performance of Redshift over Hive in EMR? Redshift is the best solution for Apache Spark in terms of performance?
Or Using Hive I will take much performance with spark that will compensates the maintenance time?

-------EDIT-------

Well I read more about it, and I found how Redshift will work with Spark in EMR.
According to what I saw, when you call the data from Redshift it will load the information to a S3 bucket like this:

[image: Spark reading from Redshift]

This information I found at [Databricks Blog](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/10/19/introducing-redshift-data-source-for-spark.html)

According this, is Hive faster than Redshift for EMR?

Comment: I think it's too broad for SO and too opinion-based - really, the best solution is to make benchmarks for specific use case

Comment: I really hope that someone here knows about it. I didn't find any benchmarks for it :(